# Scala Dispatch Simple Get Request

Tags: scala, scala-dispatch

I am trying to execute a Simple GET request with Scala Dispatch, however I am erroring out with a 404 error. Unexpected response status: 404

Here is a example that works:

`https://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=tsla,goog`

But am I amunsure of where my error is in my code

```
import dispatch._ , Defaults._  
object Main extends App {
  //concats a the proper uri together to send to google finance   
  def composeUri ( l:List[String]) = {   
    def google = host("google.com").secure
    def googleFinance = google / "finance" / "info" 
    def googleFinanceGet = googleFinance.GET
    val csv = l mkString "," 
    googleFinanceGet <<? Map("infotype"-> "infoquoteall", "q"->csv)   
  }   

  def sendRequest (uri:Req) = { 
    val res:Future[Either[Throwable,String]] = Http(uri OK as.String).either    
    res 
  } 
  val future  = sendRequest(composeUri(List("tsla","goog")))
  for (f <- future.left) yield println("There was an error" + f.getMessage) 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you print the composed URL (using `composeUri(List("tsla", "goog")).url`, for example), you'll see that it's different from your working example—it doesn't include the `www` subdomain. Change the definition of `google` to use `www.google.com` and this'll work as expected.

Comment: also, why isn't this script exiting from sbt upon completion?