# Scala dispatch example

Tags: scala

I'm a Java engineer who's been slowly learning Scala recently. I've come across some sample code using Dispatch to make a simple GET request:

```
val request = url("http://somesite.com")
val result = Http( request OK as.String)
```

The problem is... I don't quite get what's going on here. First, is Http a class? or a method? Second, what's up with the parameters passed to it? I thought maybe we were passing three arguments, with Scala allowing us to omit commas. But when I tried adding commas, I got a compilation error, so that can't be right.

I'm sure this makes sense to someone fluent in Scala, but I'm not there yet and it's holding me up. I've tried looking for documentation online, but have found nothing helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's in Scala for Java Developers, which I'm reading through, but I've also seen similar examples online; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103553/scala-dispatch-simple-get-request, and even on the Dispatch site: http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a (painfully) explicit version with all the syntactic sugar taken out:

```
import dispatch.{ Defaults, Http, Req, as, implyRequestHandlerTuple, url }
import scala.concurrent.Future

val request: Req = url.apply("http://somesite.com")

val result: Future[String] =
  Http.apply(
    implyRequestHandlerTuple(request).OK[String](as.String)
  )(Defaults.executor)
```

[`url`](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/v0.11.2/core/src/main/scala/requests.scala#L56) is a singleton object with an `apply` method that returns an instance of the `Req` case class. [`Http`](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/0.11.3/core/src/main/scala/execution.scala#L29) is also a singleton object, and it also has an `apply` method. `Http`'s `apply` takes two parameter lists—the first taking a single `Req` parameter, and the second taking an execution context (which you can think of as Scala's version of Java's [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)).

[`implyRequestHandlerTuple`](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/0.11.3/core/src/main/scala/package.scala#L13) is an *implicit* method. `Req` doesn't have an `OK` method, but the compiler knows that the `RequestHandlerTupleBuilder` class does (and that it takes the appropriate arguments—in this case a function from `Response` to some type), so in the original version it automatically applies this method to make the conversion from `Req`.

Finally, `as` is a package that contains a [`String`](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/0.11.3/core/src/main/scala/as/core.scala#L12) singleton object. This object extends `Response => String` (which is more syntactic sugar for `Function1[Response, String]`. Our `OK` method was looking for a function taking a `Response`, so we're good there.

In the end you've got a `Future[String]`. There are plenty of [other places](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) to read about futures, so I won't go into detail here, but in short this value can either be unsatisfied (i.e. you're still waiting for a result), or satisfied with a failure (in case of network error, etc.), or satisfied successfully (in which case it'll contain the response body).

Comment: Maybe you started 12 secs earlier, or maybe you know what words to leave out. Your humanities education dollars at work. I'm going to have my daughter read this answer before she starts on her next book report. I see you use the transition words recommended by Ms Roberts: "finally," "in the end." Check-plus!

Answer (score 9):

`url` is (essentially) a method that returns a `Req` object. So `request` has type `Req`.

`Http` is a class with a companion object that has a few overloads of the `apply` method. So when you see:

```
Http(request OK as.String)
```

It is actually syntactic sugar for:

```
Http.apply(request OK as.String)
```

Ok, so what's going on inside `apply`? It appears as though a method named `OK` is being called on `request`. But looking through the [API Docs](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.databinder.dispatch/dispatch-core_2.11/0.11.2), you may notice there is no such method `OK` for the type `Req`. There is, however, a class called `RequestHandlerTupleBuilder`, which does have such a method. And there is an implicit conversion defined in the `dispatch` package:

```
implicit def implyRequestHandlerTuple(builder: Req) =
    new RequestHandlerTupleBuilder(builder)
```

What's happening here is that when you call `request OK`, the compiler sees that `request` does not have an `OK` method. So it then looks for possible implicit methods that accept `Req` as a parameter and return types to do have such a method. The above method is the implicit it finds, so the `Req` is implicitly converted to a `RequestHandlerTupleBuilder`.

Now let's look at the signature of `OK`:

```
def OK [T](f: Response => T): (Request, OkFunctionHandler[T])
```

It accepts a function as a parameter. In particular, a function that accepts a `Response` as a parameter, and returns some other type `T`. In this case, such a function is `as.String` that has type `Response => String`. `OK` will then return a `Request` tupled with an `OkFunctionHandler[T]`.

This tells me that the overload of `apply` we're calling is this one:

```
def apply[T](pair: (Request, AsyncHandler[T])): Future[T]
```

(`OkFunctionHandler` extends `AsyncHandler`)

Looking it all in a slightly more java-like style and with type annotations, you have:

```
val request: Req = url("http://somesite.com")
val result: Future[String] = Http.apply(request.OK(as.String))
```

Using only explicit calls, it would look more like:

```
val result: Future[String] = 
    Http.apply(implyRequestHandlerTuple(request).OK(as.String))
```

In short, there is only one parameter being passed to `Http.apply`, it's just using a point-free style to call other methods within.

Comment: Wow, I think I beat you by 12 seconds. I like your answer as well, but you could be clearer about the fact that `request OK as.String` is parsed as `request.OK(as.String)`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Hard to be clearer than explication at bottom. But is `url` essentially a method? That would be ok if ScalaDoc had a "use case" where you click on a method `url` and it takes you to the object-with-an-apply. I hope the ScalaDoc folks aren't reading this.

Comment: I glazed over `url`, because the OP wasn't really asking about it. Now I have an unofficial measurement of how many of me it takes to make one @TravisBrown.

Comment: Have a +1 to even the gap a bit. :)